# Do black market items carry through characters?

Tags: borderlands-2

I can't get my head around the wording of the black market. Does it carry between saves or does it just effect my current Siren?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Black Market upgrades only affect your current character. Further, each save maintains its own Eridium reserve.

The only upgrades that affect all characters on your account are Badass Rank Bonus Stat upgrades and Skin Customizations.