# Do skins carry between characters?

Tags: borderlands-2

I had previously been under the impression that [skins carry over between characters](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/85497/4775), but while playing the slots with my other character I realized that all the "[Vendor] customer service" skins were all able to be used again. I'm positive that my main character already had these unlocked.

Which skins (if any) carry between characters?  I got in on the [Halloween skins](https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.10151145529449081.459362.104080139080&type=1) and since we can only get one for each character, I'd hate to waste it on a character if it won't carry over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [Sean's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/85045/21619), skins carry over, but have to be unlocked per class. Some are also class specific. So if you unlocked it for your old class, you may still need to unlock it for the new one.

Comment: That's just it, though - the skins you get from the slot machine drop for random classes (unlike quest rewards). My current theory is that maybe I haven't gambled since the release of the Mechromancer pack and I was only unlocking Mechromancer skins. I wasn't paying enough attention, though... :/

Comment: @DaveMcClelland Discounting bugs in the game, for any skin you have already unlocked you should see [clear red text](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85759/is-there-a-quick-way-to-determine-if-i-already-have-a-skin-customization) when you look at it.  If you do not have this text, the game thinks you have not unlocked it.  Bugs have been reported that wipe your progress, but I have not personally run into any.

Comment: I've seen the "already unlocked" notification on a bunch of skins already. Unless I can find an example of a skin I can prove I already have unlocked on another character, I'll assume I'm just going crazy and it was a new Mechromancer skin or something. Thanks for the help

Comment: @DaveMcClelland yeah, mechromancer skins suddenly appeared after the update so you'll notice a lot of those